# Getting a field in Scala json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

How do I get a particular field out of a Json object in Scala?  I feel like I'm going in circles.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

val me = parse(""" {"name":"brian", "state":"frustrated"} """)
```

Now I want just the state.  I was looking for something like

```
me("state") -> "frustrated"
```

I have tried

```
me("state")
me.get("state")
me \ "state" <thanks for the idea>
me['state']
me.state
me.NOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!
```

Help?

Comment: Have you tried.. me \ "state". Check out the test spec https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/tests/src/test/scala/org/json4s/ExtractionExamplesSpec.scala

Comment: @m-z fixed the typo, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your code has errta, and below may be right code.

Assume type of value in state field is fixed, say its type is string.

```
val me = parse("""{"name":"brian", "state":"frustrated"}""")
val JString(state) = me \ "state"
```

Comment: that is a very foreign syntax to me.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrianDolan Can you check the type of state? The expression "state.isInstanceOf[String]" is value of String.

Comment: it was my error, deleted the comment. I really appreciate your help.  Now I have to get into nested fields.